# How to implement a custom Spring Http Message Converter for writing a typed Collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I've got a Spring Boot Controller that returns a `List<Person>` and I would like to implement a custom `HttpMessageConverter` that can write collections of type `Person`.

I see `AbstractHttpMessageConverter`, but the `supports()` method only takes a Class, so I can test for Collection, but no way (as far as I know) to test for a Collection of type Person.

I also see `GenericHttpMessageConverter` and `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter` which sound promising, but I can't figure out to properly implement one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. The following seems to work...

```java
@Component
static class PersonMessageConverter
    extends AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<Collection<Person>> {

  public PersonMessageConverter() {
    super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    TypeToken<Collection<Person>> personCollectionType = new com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<>() {};
    return canWrite(mediaType) && personCollectionType.isSupertypeOf(type);
  }

  @Override
  protected void writeInternal(Collection<Person> persons, Type type, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
      throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    // do write...
  }

  // continue with read methods here
}
```