# How to differentiate between different converters in Java Spring using the canWrite method

Tags: java, spring, csv, converters

I am currently working on a Java Spring project and I am coming across some issues when doing content negotiation. Specifically, the csv conversion. I have my converters ready, however, it seems that I am having trouble differentiating between what kind of converter should be used when.

I am aware of the `canWrite` method in the `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter`. However, I am not able to find a way to differentiate between the converters.

Consider my config file:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(@NotNull List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new CountryConverter());
    converters.add(new CountriesConverter());

    converters.add(new YearConverter());
    converters.add(new YearsConverter());
}
```

A `countriesConverter` converts a list of countries to csv whilst a `YearsConverter` converts a list of years to csv. Now, the problem is, I believe that there is not enough information that is given in the `canWrite` method to be able to differentiate between the two classes. I was wondering if I could get some insight on how to do it.

Here is my `CountriesConverter` with the `canWrite` method.

```
@Override
public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType) && clazz.getName().contains("$SubList"));
}
```

Here is my `YearsConverter` with the `canWriteMethod`

```
@Override
public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType) && clazz.getName().contains("$SubList"));
}
```

How can I differentiate between the converters and what kind of List they should be converting?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67182922/6398325

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The type I receive does not seem to correctly represent the object I have. It just states that it is of type "Object" which is very confusing.